# What could be the reason covid19 death data shows strong periodic trends?

Tags: time-series

The covid19 death data for US shows strong periodic trends. It does not make sense to me that people die periodically.

What could be the reason to having such data? I thought it might be the reporting artifacts, for example, people always update data at Monday, but the period seems to be 3-4 days.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's off-topic, because you should ask an epidemiologist about this. It also could be about data gathering, but then still it's not really on statistics per se. Moreover, this sounds like a guessing game & there could be a lot of factors, that possibly interact with each other.

Comment: The other question asked about the data itself, here you ask rather to *explain* the trend. To explain it, one would need either to have domain knowledge on epidemiology (so off-topic in here), or have some additional data. From the data itself one could just confirm that there are cycles, or what are their properties (e.g. cycle length), but not answer the "why" question.

Comment: I see about seven dips between 5 April and 23 May, so my first suspicion would be a weekly cycle with the recording of deaths affected by working days

Comment: It's *obviously* a weekly cycle.  Guess where the weekends are ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some comments point out, the *reason* for this is probably not a statistical one but something about how the data are gathered.

Nevertheless, there are statistical things you can do here. Some that come to mind are

1. Apply a smooth to the curve to eliminate the bumps
2. Model death rate as a function of time and whether the day is a weekend or not.
3. Decompose the series into trend, weekly effects, and other effect.